# How to call service based classes from entity class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is an entity class of my Multi-tenancy project

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
private String uniqueCustomerId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@Convert(converter = CryptoConverter.class)
private String mobile;
private String mobileShavalue;
}
```

In my CryptoConverter.java I am checking whether I have to encrypt this attribute or not, from the configuration and encryption logic written in CryptoConverter.java. Also, if the configuration tells that i have to encrypt the mobile attribute then in that case i have to also store the sha value(sha1 or sha2 from config) for attribute mobileShavalue.

One thing came in my mind to achieve this, is through using  @PrePersist in my entity class and again getting configuration from PrePersist method to validate whether I have to store mobile sha value or not and writing shavalue logic there.

But when I do this I am getting below error

```
@Autowired
EncryptionConfigService encryptionConfigService;

@PrePersist
private void doSomeCode(){
    encryptionConfigService.callNewMethod();
}
```

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.loylty.tms.service.EncryptionConfigService, at table: Customer, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(encryption_config_service)]

Answer (score 1):

Annotate the autowired service with @Transient to make the ORM ignore it during serialization

```
@Transient
@Autowired
EncryptionConfigService encryptionConfigService;

@PrePersist
private void doSomeCode(){
    encryptionConfigService.callNewMethod();
}
```

Comment: but I am getting encryptionConfigService as null at that point

Answer (score 0):

you cannot simply autowire spring beans into an entity class which is managed the persistence layer (e.g. hibernate) and is not a spring bean.
You could use an EntityListener instead to connect the two worlds.

So create a dedicated EntityListener class and make it a spring bean by annotating with @Component. Then you can wire up your dependencies as desired:

```
@Component
public class EncryptionEntityListener {
   @Autowired
   private EncryptionConfigService encryptionConfigService;

   @PrePersist
   public void doSomeCode(Object targetEntity){
      var encrypted = encryptionConfigService.callNewMethod();

      // of course do a type check on the targetEntity first :-)
      targetEntity.setEncrypted(encrypted);
   }
}
```

In the Entity itself you register the listener like this:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(EncryptionEntityListener.class)
public class Customer {
```