# How to get a class object in @PrePersist method

Tags: java, spring

This is my class

```
public class Customer{

    private String programId;
    private String entityName;
    private String columnName;

    @PrePersist
    doSomething(){
        doSomeService.newMethod(//how can I pass class object here with all its values);
    }

}
```

I want to access few attributes of class in my prepersist to do some logic , is it possible to get class object with its values inside PrePersist method

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything overly complex in `@PrePersist`. Certainly not calling other services. Your question about "class object with its values" is unclear.

Comment: Why we should not write complex things there ?

Comment: Because when you're in one of the callback methods you're actually in the middle of something. In the case of `@PrePersist` you're in the middle of persisting the entity, and complex operations may cause problems. It's [forbidden](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) to use `EntityManager` or `Query` methods for example. Invoking a service from an entity is highly suspicious in **any** case, and doing it in `@PrePersist` just makes it more suspicious. I strongly suggest you change your design so the entity doesn't need a dependency to a service.

Comment: This was my requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59067687/how-to-call-service-based-classes-from-entity-class-in-spring-boot

Comment: Then I'd suggest an `EntityListener` instead of annotated methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below

```
@PrePersist
private void beforeSave( Customer customer )
{

}
```